# Swift- access enumeration by type

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an enum in Swift. It's kind of like

```
enum LegalArgs {
    case AsString(String)
    case AsBool(Bool)
    ... etc
}
```

I want to access this enum conditionally *by type*. So if I have an instance of LegalArgs, I can pass T and get back a T? if the instance was of that type. Otherwise I will have to duplicate a bunch of code for different cases.

My current code looks a bit like this:

```
String? maybeAsString(arg: LegalArgs) {
    switch arg {
    case .AsString(let str):
        return str;
    default:
        return nil;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I've got to duplicate this function for every case in the enum.

Comment: Do you want an `init` that takes `Any` and makes an `enum` for the according real type of the associated value? So `LegalArgs("Hello")` would result in `LegalArgs.AsString("Hello")`?

Comment: No, the other way around - I have LegalArgs.AsString("hello") and I need a String?. This is simple enough to do for a specific member but more problematic when I need to share the same logic among all cases with different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic `asType` function:

```
enum LegalArgs {
    case AsString(String)
    case AsBool(Bool)
    case AsNumber(Int)

    func asType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        switch self {
        case AsString(let str): return str as? T
        case AsBool(let bol): return bol as? T
        case AsNumber(let num): return num as? T
        }
    }
}

// usage
LegalArgs.AsBool(true).asType(Bool.self) // true
LegalArgs.AsBool(true).asType(String.self) // nil
```

Comment: This doesn't completely solve my problem... but it's almost certainly close enough. I will attempt this the next time I am working on this codebase.

Comment: @Puppy What should be changed in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, I'd still need to manually keep asType<T> in sync with the underlying enum, and for every enum where I need this function, I'll need to rewrite it myself, rather than having a language tool to do it. I mean, that tool probably does not exist so this is the best possible solution, but it's not *quite* as good as it could be in principle.

Comment: @Puppy In this case you have to wait for a language feature which could return the associated values as tuples of type `Any`. But personally I don't think that gets such a feature... Hoping for it to come.

Comment: This answer worked for me, except for the part where actually using it crashed the compiler, which is not your fault.